# Junit: unexpected invocation after upgrading MyBatis to 3.1.1

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mybatis

Scenario:

```
final CatalogRuleExample example = new CatalogRuleExample();
example.createCriteria().andCatalogIdEqualTo(catalogId);
example.setOrderByClause("position ASC");

final List<CatalogRuleRecord> records = new ArrayList<CatalogRuleRecord>();
final CatalogRuleRecord firstRecord = new CatalogRuleRecord();
final CatalogRuleRecord secondRecord = new CatalogRuleRecord();
records.add(firstRecord);
records.add(secondRecord);
mockery.checking(new Expectations() {
  {
    oneOf(catalogRuleDAO).selectByExample(example);
    will(returnValue(records));
```

...

Problem:

The final example of CatalogRuleExample is not the same in my mockery.checking by selectByExample. If i override the equals() it will work. But i wanted to know, if there is a better solution for this case. Thanks in advance
PS: this same code worked bevor i migrate from Ibatis to Mybtis

```
final CatalogRuleExample example = new CatalogRuleExample() {
  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object that) {
    if (that instanceof CatalogRuleExample) {
      CatalogRuleExample other = (CatalogRuleExample) that;
      if (other.getOredCriteria().size() != 1) {
        return false;
      }
      if (other.getOredCriteria().get(0).getCriteria().size() != 1) {
        return false;
      }
      if (!other.getOredCriteria().get(0).getCriteria().get(0).getValue().equals(catalogId)) {
        return false;
      }
      if (!other.getOrderByClause().equals("position ASC")) {
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
};
```

ERROR:
unexpected invocation: catalogRuleDAO.selectByExample(<com.protogo.persistence.dao.CatalogRuleExample@a6ca0ea9>)
expectations:
  expected once, never invoked: catalogRuleDAO.selectByExample(<com.protogo.persistence.dao.CatalogRuleExample@66e1beb1>); returns <[com.protogo.persistence.data.CatalogRuleRecord@4f7d02c2, com.protogo.persistence.data.CatalogRuleRecord@4f7d02c2]>

Comment: could someone then pls point me out, where i can find something about this issue. I am on it since 2 days and cant understand why the ERROR: unexpected invocation is there...

Comment: This looks to be an issue that would require seeing a lot more of your code base, such as the MyBatis mapper(s) and overall structure to see how/when your "selectByExample" method should be called.  You could try to post more of that here, but perhaps you'll need to post more of it somewhere else (say on GitHub?) to get help.

Comment: Thanks. I found something that could help me further
http://richgski.blogspot.de/2012/04/mybatis-generator-generic-example-class.html
http://www.mybatis.org/generator/generatedobjects/extendingExampleClass.html